# DFSR: Break large replication group into multiple smaller replication groups?

Tags: windows, windows-server-2008-r2, replication, dfs-r

**Is there a way to break a very large replication group into smaller replication groups while avoiding a huge backlog while it re-syncs or verifies the files in each smaller replication group?**

I have a very large replication group that covers 450,000 files and is 1.5TB and it has a lot of activity coming from three separate offices in three different cities, two of which are 1000+ miles apart.  I have already structured a new DFS Namespace to handle the addressing of the new smaller replication groups and that is working well.  But the question here is how to go about breaking the actual replication group itself into smaller chunks.

This is needed because some offices don't need big chunks of that existing replication group and sometimes we want a local representation of part of that directory structure to show what is local only and not replicate that portion (like a temp directory of sorts).